How feasible would it be to "kill" the Sun by using blood?
Basically, my hivemind, which embodies the concept of murder, wants to "kill" the Sun. It does this by teleporting an amount of human blood equivalent to four times the mass of the Sun within the Sun itself. The intention is to utilize the iron content present in the blood to induce its death. Sun death here would be the Sun no longer producing heat and light. I want the Sun to cool down.
I read that iron can accelerate the death of a star if injected with enough iron and that blood has some iron. How well would this feasibly work in killing the Sun?

Please define "kill" and "sun death." Are black holes and nova a solution? Or are you simply tying to force it to cool down until the nuclear process stops? Or maybe something else?

@JBH Cooling down

Can you be more specific with what you want to know. Perhaps mcguffin plus technobabble is sufficiently feasible for you. Perhaps you want to borrow time on a compute cluster and pass peer review from astrophysicists. Remember that the standard for this site is more than answerable. It also includes specificity, and not being POB. Who’s opinion of feasibility do you care about?

I've gotta admit, @sphennings has a good point. You have a hive mind sending 4X the mass of the sun in human blood to its center. Does it matter if it's feasible? This would make a great graphic novel.

If you'd had the [science-fantasy] and asked us how to achieve this (including blood somehow), then maybe.

Perhaps relevant: https://goonshow.org/goonshow/s5p22/

If you want to add iron, I'd suggest you actually add mostly iron! It's a bit like asking "I have heard that too much salt kills people. How much mineral water do I have to drink in order to kill myself?" It doesn't work that way ;-).

Does blood still count as blood when it's a soup of quarks, gluons, and photons? You can blow up anything with anything if you just get a suitably powerful wizard to give it enough internal kinetic energy. $10^{42} J$ should do the job for the Sun.

Blood is mostly water.  As usual, Randall Munroe has already answered your question: https://what-if.xkcd.com/14/

@RonJohn Although since it was short answer, he didn't run the numbers on what preposterous amount of water you'd need to induce some kind of exotic supernova.

Are they creating the blood with magic or are they pulling it out of actual humans? Because getting together enough humans to produce that much blood in the first place has its own problems.

TL;DR: Not feasible at all.
Consider the composition of blood.  Blood is mainly water (hydrogen and oxygen) with red blood cells packed with hemoglobin, each unit of which holds a few atoms of iron, amongst a whole lot of CHONPS - the atoms from which most organisms are made.
Now, You may have heard that Iron is what 'kills' stars, and in a way, that is true, but that's only when the star's lighter elements have mostly been fused to iron, so that the outward forces of fusion can no longer balance the inward forces of gravity.
However, by adding a whole lot of blood, you're adding a whole lot of hydrogen, plus quite a lot of heavier elements, and just a little iron.  All that additional hydrogen, plus the mass of all the other stuff will have exactly the opposite effect than the one you're looking for: the hydrogen will begin to fuse, and the other elements will increase the sun's gravity... so while the sun's transition into helium-fusion will be delayed, the sun will transform from a G-class star to something a little larger and much hotter, probably a B class star given its mass of 5 suns (M☉).  See Stellar Classification.
It could be considered that when compared to a star, blood has a lot of carbon and oxygen, and not all that much hydrogen by weight.  A 4 M☉ blob of blood would approach the composition of a white dwarf star... and its 4 M☉ would result in a mass of carbon and oxygen greater than the Chandrasekhar limit of 1.4 M☉.  However, with the sun's hydrogen plus the minimal hydrogen in the blood, this would likely inject enough energy from hydrogen fusion to prevent collapse of the carbon-oxygen core to produce a supernova similar to a Type 1a supernova.
We can even imagine what would happen when this Murder Hivemind magics up 4 M☉ of blood - at the traditional temperature of 37°C - within the sun.  Since the sun's core is about 15,000,000K, and blood is about 310K, the temperature of the sun's core would temporarily be averaged out to a mere 3,000,000K or so... far less than required for atomic fusion.  The sun would appear to swell up and go out... momentarily.
Success!...?  The sun would appear to go dark... perhaps to a dull, blood red.  Average the sun's surface temperature of 5772K with the blood's temperature of 310K (and its 4 times greater quantity), we get around 1216K/943°C.  If we look at black body objects at that temperature, and compare it to this chart from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-body_radiation:


From https://www.tec-science.com/thermodynamics/temperature/black-body-radiation/
Once we filter the light through Earth's atmosphere, it'll look even redder.
However, the mass of mixed hydrogen and blood would collapse under its own gravity, and when we're talking about stars, temperature and pressure are pretty much the same thing.  Pressure would rapidly increase, the residual temperature of the sun's matter would cause the dissociation of molecular bonds in the blood, and then turn it into a plasma.  As the pressure increased, atomic fusion would resume... and because of the increased mass, it would progress faster than ever before.  The dull red surface of the sun would brighten from dull, blood red to bright red, then orange, and then to its familiar yellow, and then still further, to white and then blue-white at perhaps 15,000K to 20,000K.  It might be only a little larger than it once was, but it would be much hotter.  This would all likely happen within hours.
There will be death associated with this... but it will be the death of Earth's life forms, as increased solar radiation increases its temperature much as if the sun had become a red giant... save that the burned cinder of Earth won't necessarily be swallowed.  It's orbit will be reduced considerably due to the sun's greater mass, though.
If we were to go the other way, and attempt to initiate a core-collapse supernova by adding so much iron that it collapsed into degeneracy, we would need to add perhaps 1.4 M☉ of iron.  How much blood would this take?
Well, since blood contains on average around 1163 micrograms of iron per decilitre (or about 1.163 milligram per litre) and blood is 1.06 g/cc or 1.06 kg/l, blood is about 1 part in 100000 iron by weight.
So, since Iron is only 0.2% of the sun's mass, to add 1.4 M☉ of iron by adding blood, we would have to add 140,000 M☉ of blood.  This is far beyond the 40-50 solar mass limit of a star that can undergo a type II/core collapse supernova.  I would suspect that accumulating such a stupendous amount of mass in one place would result in the immediate collapse of the whole lot into a black hole in a failed supernova.

Part of me is curious to go "Myth Busters" on this and calculate how much blood would be necessary to have enough iron to induce a core collapse super nova.

@GregBurghardt Done... but it's not going to happen the way you expect either.

@GregBurghardt You can't just calculate the amount of iron. A big part of Monty's answer is all those lighter elements in much more plentiful proportion than the iron. Somewhat like throwing water on a super hot fire, you're adding fuel to inject a pinch of fire retardant. I wouldn't be surprised that in the effort to kill the sun, one turned it into a black hole.

Technically the star is dead. It collapsed into a black hole. So, whaddya say, Monte. Do we call this one plausible?

(and I'm hoping people pick up on the "Myth Busters" reference, but it's late and it might sound better in my head than in my comment)

@GregBurghardt If you keep adding blood, beyond the 4 solar mass amount the OP suggested, it'll eventually collapse into a black hole.  But at 5 solar masses total, you don't have a black hole, you have a B or A class star.

Maybe worth adding that, in making the sun bigger and brighter, the hivemind would cause the sun's lifetime to be shortened. Given that the amount of C and O added does exceed the Chandrasekhar limit, but the total mass is only 5 M☉, I suspect the eventual outcome would be a supernova, since there would not be enough mass in the envelope to contain the "carbon flash".  However, I think that the lifetime depends also on where exactly the blood is added. The core? The envelope? Uniformly mixed? In any case, the result is far from standard models of stellar evolution.

in a sense it will kill the star, more massive star burn through their fuel faster, so it will dratically shorten the life of the sun, still in the billions of years though.

@John While the (unmodified) sun has an estimated total lifespan of 10 billion years, the modified B-class star might have a lifespan on the order of 100 million years... or less, since so much of its mass is now oxygen and carbon.

I understand that theoretically the sun dulls in brightness momentarily. Would it actually be noticeable in any way, and at what time? Unless we count the absorption and re-emmitting of light as 'new' light, most of the light is thousands of years old. It can take a while before we see a flicker of darkness. The added mass could even shake up the layers, potentially shedding a lot of light much quicker than before. What's your (professional?) take on this?

@Trioxidane If the blood reaches all the way to the surface, the dimming will be pretty much immediate.  Brightening will depend upon the time it takes for the renewed fusion energy to reach the surface, as I said, probably hours with convection.

@GregBurghardt, adding more fuel to the mix also increases the photonic pressure, which pushes out on the extra mass, resulting in the star being bigger than the schwarzschild radius

I think there's a far worse problem.  You have a star with 1 solar mass that suddenly becomes 5 solar masses.  The pressure inside the star was supporting 1 solar mass, it's now subject to 5 solar masses.  Your star is going crunch--but it has enough fuel that this results in a ginormous outpouring of energy rather than going down the event horizon.  You do not want to be anywhere nearby when that happens.

And exactly how is that blood distributed?  Evenly across the volume of the star?  The new mass is going to get redistributed into equilibrium--releasing another ginormous amount of energy that you do not want to be anywhere nearby.

The sun is over 300,000 times the mass of earth, unless the hivemind uses humans from all colonies across the galaxy or something like that not even the entire biomass of everything on earth would make any real impact on the sun.
add to that how human and animal blood has a very low concentration of blood and if humans have spread across many galaxies than maybe the hivemind could scrape together enough blood to affect the sun in any meaningful way but obviously it makes no sense because it would be far easier to try to mess with the sun using iron from planetary cores, the asteroid belt / Oort Cloud, etc..
That is a far higher concentration of iron and also a far higher amount, especially the Oort Cloud might contain enough iron to make it work
Or, just have the hivemind sing the sun to death like in Revelation Death a star is sung to death by the Inhibitors.
